# AWS Management Console - change default from S3?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have nothing against S3, but just don't use it.  Every single time I log into the AWS management console the one thing I want to do is manage my EC2 instances.

Does anyone know how to simply make EC2 the default item on my console screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't found any configuration for this either but I do use a very simple workaround. Bookmark your favored default.

E.g. if you want to land on ec2, region eu-west after you login you would use:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=eu-west-1

Answer (score 3):

If you click on the orange cube tab on the far left of the tabs on the console page, there is a dropdown that allows you to set the defaulr service page called:

Set Start Page

Answer (score 0):

you need to create new policy and need to add below line in JSON

```
"Condition": {"StringEquals": {"aws:RequestedRegion": "ap-south-1"}}
```

**below is my entire json** for Mumbai region

```
   {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": "ap-south-1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```